# Find totals for each category based on categorization

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using numbers to categorize items in a list, each with a $ amount.

Column A has a number, 1-15, depending on the item in column B. Column C has the cost of the item in column B.

I want to find the total cost of all the items with the number 1, same for number 2, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try query() in this way:

```
=QUERY(B2:C,"select B, sum(C) where B is not null group by B label B 'item'")
```

[image: query]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [**Pivot Table**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en) - this tool is designed to solve just such tasks

[image: PivotTable]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `A2:C` with a header row on top of it in row 1, use `query()` like this:

`=query(A1:C, "select A, sum(C) where A is not null group by A", 1)`

The `1` specifies the number of header rows.

Comment: OP said"I want to find the total cost of all the `items`", so I preferred (and I think it is better) to use column B and not A in the query, so that items appear in the result instead of numbers

Comment: Hmm... the OP also said _"find the total cost of all the items **with the number 1, same for number 2, and so on**."_